# Function kepps after return ( Recursion C)

Tags: c, recursion, return

This is my code:

```
int Binary (int* arr, unsigned int size, int num)
{

    if (0 == size)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (1 == size)
    {
        if (arr[0] == num)
        {
            return 0;
        }    
        return -1;
    }

    size/= 2;
    if (num == arr[size])
    {
        return size;
    }
    else
    {
        if (num < arr[size])
        {
            Binary (arr, size, num);
        }
        else
        {
            Binary (&arr[size+1], size, num);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

It doesn't work.
When I debug it (trying to search a number that appears in an array), I see that it goes into the line of 'return size', which it should do (side question- is there a way to put line numbers in the code..) but then it keeps going to the last line and returns -1.
How come I have a return and it doesn't go out of the function?
I first tried not to put any return in the end because I am not supposed to reach to the end, but the compiler says "control reaches end of non-void function" so I added the last return, but obviously it is not the right thing to do..

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to say because you didn't mention what debugger you're using.  But it's likely that the return occurred from one of the recursive call sites of the `if`, and the next step after the call was the return -1;

Comment: `Binary (&arr[size+1], size, num);` is wrong. : E.g `int a[] = {11,22}; int index = Binary (a, 2, 33);` ==> `size/= 2;` : `size` become `1` ==> `Binary (&arr[size+1], size, num);` ==> `Binary (&arr[1+1], 1, 33);` : `&arr[1+1]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return the results of the recursive call

```
int Binary (int* arr, unsigned int size, int num)
{

    if (0 == size)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (1 == size)
    {
        if (arr[0] == num)
        {
            return 0;
        }    
        return -1;
    }

    size/= 2;
    if (num == arr[size])
    {
        return size;
    }
    else
    {
        if (num < arr[size])
        {
            return Binary (arr, size, num); // Added return
        }
        else
        {
            return Binary (&arr[size+1], size, num); // Added return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The best alternative is to get rid of the recursion entirely. If that's not an option, for reasons unknown, I'd write the last part of the function so that the pointer and size variables are prepared in advance. Then at the very end have one single return statement with the recursive call. Otherwise I wouldn't trust compilers to tail optimize this code properly, meaning it will not be inlined. Meaning it will be a slow, buggy mess.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced recursive call to:

```
  return Binary (arr, size, num);
//^^^^^^
```

Currently, you are just calling the function and ignoring the return value.

---

> but then it keeps going to the last line and `returns -1`.

It is actually the parent going into `return -1`

Comment: Any reason for downvote?  OP code should contain `return`. What do you expect, do not answer or post the complete code?